# SELECT an item in a database then UPDATE?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

**EDIT:** Let me rephrase the question, how do I write the database query to say something like this.. `PUT $_POST['y'] WHERE column is 'slug' and term_id = 100` obviously not proper sql syntax.. but I think something like this will fit my need? right..

Im trying to update an item in my database, using a value of a dynamic variable(meaning the variable changes quite often) on each change I dont want to add a new row (which is what is doing) instead I want to keep that one row and update one part...

```
    global $wpdb;
```

Some Variables, this stuff goes into my data tables

```
    //The data here comes from an ajax call
    $_POST['y'];

    $term_id = 100; 
    $name = 'Code Snippet'; 
    $slug = 'code-snippet';
```

A variable to setup the columns I will be inserting data into...

```
    //Im adding into wp_terms a default table (for testing)... 
    $query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->terms (term_id, name, slug) VALUES (%d, %s, %s)";
```

I take the `$query` variable and fill the tables with the variables declared above

```
    //Here I insert the data into the columns 
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, $term_id, $name, $slug));
```

I can update the slug column we declared as 'code-snippet' with my dynamic value $_POST['y'], but only once... how do I keep updating it?

```
//Here is where I struggle.. 
$wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['y']), array('slug' => 'code-snippet'));

    die();
```

**UPDATE ADDED AJAX CODE IN CASE...** (It works fine.. I am just focused on updating a row when a new ajax call is made... I can create a new row when ajax call is made.. just dont know how to query it so that it replaces old ajax value)

```
     $( ".silly-string" ).draggable({
    containment: '#_moon_static_bg_status',

     stop: function(event, ui) {
         var pos_x = ui.position.left;
         var pos_y = ui.position.top;

         jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: window.ajaxurl,
            data: { "action": "myAjax", x: pos_x, y: pos_y }}).done(function( msg ) {
             $('.silly-string').text( "Data Saved: " + msg );
         });    
      }  
});
```

**UPDATE:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/agL0U.jpg

You can see from the image where the `648` is that used to be `'code-snippet'` but when the number is changed to say `723` it does not update.. obviously because we tell it to update `'code-snippet'` I am trying to figure out how to write it so that it matches what I need..

**UPDATE:** I hope this can show the simplicity of what I am trying to achieve

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxeo1.jpg

**SOLVED:** Thanks to @Matt Cooper I was able to realize how easy this was, and now I Can actually do what I want. I also learned a few things in the process that I can use in the future, I now posses a little more coding power knowing how to interact with the wordpress database, it was hell reading tutorial upon tutorial but that's how you learn...

**THE SOLUTION:** I added a new ajax variable, which returns the ID of the draggable element.. `var divid = ui.helper.attr("id");` (had to make sure to give the element an ID) Here is the full code..

**AJAX:** I added a new variable `var divid = ui.helper.attr("id");` and added it into the data to be passed

```
    $( ".silly-string" ).draggable({
    containment: '#_moon_static_bg_status',

     stop: function(event, ui) {
         var pos_x = ui.position.left;
         var pos_y = ui.position.top;
         var divid = ui.helper.attr("id");

         jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: window.ajaxurl,
            data: { "action": "myAjax", id: divid, x: pos_x, y: pos_y }})   
      }  
});
```

**PHP:**

```
     //The data here comes from an ajax call
    $_POST['y'];
    $_POST['id']; 

    $term_id = 100; 
    $name = $_POST['id']; 
    $slug = $_POST['y']; 

    //Im adding into wp_terms a default table (for testing)... 
    $query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->terms (term_id, name, slug) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"; 

    //Here I insert the ajax data into the columns 
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, $term_id, $name, $slug));

  //$wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['y']), array('post_id' => $_POST['id'])); 
    $wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['y']), array('name' => $_POST['id']));

    $last_title = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE name = 'Code Snippet' ");  
    echo $last_title[3];

    die();
```

Comment: Is this a Wordpress limitation? Most databases don't have any problem with letting you update a row multiple times.

Comment: I just dont know how to write the database query to update an item with a dynamic variable.. What happens is I specify what needs to be updated here 'code-snippet' is inserted by default then 'code-snippet' changes on UPDATE into what my variable value is... which is a number so now 'code-snippet' becomes something like 663

Comment: what is your ajaxurl and you are getting any error first time set your ajax url static then use dynamic example http://localhost/wp/custom/plugin/plugin-name/file.php

Comment: No ajax is fine.. check the update in the OP at the very bottom.. it shows the DB table.. the ajax is outputting exactly what I want.. I am new to DB work.. I need a better DB query syntax.. I need to prevent multiple rows from being created.. and insert data into one row.. I checked the ajax in my console, its fine... I know what the problem is and its that im illiterate in database syntax haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your Update command isn't foolproof, let's walk through the code.

```
$wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['y']), array('slug' => 'code-snippet'));
```

This sends a SQL Command saying "Update the records where the slug is `code-snippet` and change it to `$_POST['y']`.

So our database contains

```
term_id | name         | slug
100       Code Snippet   $_POST['y']
```

You can probably see by now that next time you call

```
$wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['y']), array('slug' => 'code-snippet'));
```

it won't find a record where the slug field is `code-snippet` and it will fail.

I recommend instead using `term_id` (or any other unique field) as the where clause in your update.

Comment: This is exactly the problem, I just spent the last 24-48 hours cramming in all I could about $wpdb and databases... I realize the SQL query is off.. but I am not sure how to write it to be more flexiable/dynamic... One thing I tried was using the same variable that outputs something like 663 as my term_id and this is somewhat good it creates a new ROW on my value each time there is a new value, but instead of a new row I want to replace data in that same row

Comment: I think your Ajax call needs to contain some more data, You could add in an ID as well or you could pass in the current slug. It depends on the sort of data you have available at that point.

Comment: Its jquery UI draggable.. the ajax holds the position, on STOP: the ajax call is made... I use a function to send the ajax data to the wpdb... there it receives well, I am just a noob to database stuff and especially proper syntax for a query.. I dont feel its an issue with ajax, just my lack of writing a proper query

Comment: Ok I am re-reading your post.. I forgot to try what you recommended and I will see what term_id as the where clause...

Comment: Okay, So you have unique keys available based on what you've been dragging right? Dragable stop takes two parameters, event and ui. I presume you're already using ui.position to get your 'y' value. ui.helper contains a pointer to the object that was being dragged. so you could use ui.helper.attr("id") to get the id of that element. Then if you add it in as another parameter in the ajax call it should be available to your db script.

Comment: It's already available... actually if I write $wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['y']), array('slug' => $_POST['y'])); like that for every time y produces a new value on stop a new row is created in the database.. this is kinda good.. except I dont want 1 million rows... I want 1 row with the value changing.. does that make sense, I hope I explained it properly

Comment: Actually let me take that back.. similar to what I said, but in order for a new row to be created $term_id = 100; would instead be $term_id = $_POST['y']; and $slug = 'code-snippet'; would be $slug = $_POST['y']; writing the ajax data inside those variables creates a new row each time.. Ill worry about adding the X value when I get the updating row solution fixed.... You can see in the image in the OP that the value is stored in the DB

Comment: Here is a little diagram I made IDK if it will help.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/hmxYe.jpg

Comment: Okay, so if you want one row you need to use the id of the thing you're dragging, This will give you a unique key by which to update

Comment: ok, sure its simple, could you provide a small example perhaps.. I am not sleeping until I figure this out, you would be a life saver..

Comment: (sorry it's a bit late, was in a meeting.)

You need to update your ajax call firstly get var divid = ui.helper.attr("id"). Then you can send it it with x and y by changing  the data variable to  data: { "action": "myAjax", id: divid, x: pos_x, y: pos_y }})

Then you need to make use of it in Php, call it in by using $_POST['id'] then change your update to use it in the where clause. so it would become. $wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['y']), array('post_id' => $_POST['id']));

Hopefully this makes sense, it seems like the logical way to do it to me.

Comment: Yeah makes perfect sense.. let me grab a coffee and give it a crack.. ill post the result when I'm done.. thanks for taking the time..

Comment: You sir are a savior... this definitely worked, it took a little tinkering I didn't realize the WHERE clause was two different column names I was using 'slug' twice at first.. then realized I needed to change to 'post_id'... that only returned a numeric value I tried changing VALUES (%s, %s, %s) all NON integers I think... then I changed it from 'post_id' to 'name' and it worked beautifully.. thanks it feels good to solve the case..

Answer (score 0):

```
$wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['y']), array('slug' => 'code-snippet'),array( '%s' ),array( '%s' )  );
```

You can read more about update here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows

Comment: Ive been reading that codex all day.. the answer may be right under my nose.. but I am having a hard time forming logical code to match my need and update the row based on the ajax value that updates everytime a user makes an action and outputs a value...

Comment: read this article i think you are making your plug-in http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Cool am bookmarking this seems like it's on the right track for what I am seeking.. thanks for this saves me a lot of digging...